Patternfly Select Within pf-c-form
I'm trying to change the blue hover color in the attached picture to #10175f:

the code for the select is:
   <select id="otp" name="otp" class="pf-c-form-control" aria-invalid>
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="email">email</option>
        <option value="phone">phone</option>
    </select>

Can you please tell me the css property I should use to change the hover color?
Thanks
